# Inconsistent CallDirectoryExtension behavior on iOS 14.5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, call-directory-extension

After upgrading to iOS 14.5 I've noticed a strange behavior in my implementation of `CXCallDirectoryProvider`. I call a `CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.getEnabledStatusForExtension(withIdentifier: identifier)` when the app starts in `sceneWillEnterForeground`. On a new iOS version first call to `CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.getEnabledStatusForExtension(withIdentifier: identifier)` after the app has started consistently results in a long wait and a subsequent error `com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager Code=1 "(null)"`. All subsequent requests to the same method, however, execute normally, as they should.

This errorneous behavior is consistent on a new iOS 14.5 version. I've tried multiple iPhones. I'm sure that the extension identifier is valid because subsequent requests do execute normally and issues do not reproduce on any previous versions. Did someone stumble upon a similar issue?

Comment: I do see a long delay but it does eventually return the correct result. I don't get an error.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing. Long wait, then error 1 with status "unknown".